# How to make header rows for table bold using Python docx?

Tags: python, python-docx

I have created a table using the Python docx library and would like to make the header rows bold. Here is the code I am using:

```
a= doc.add_table(rows=5, cols=7)
heading_cells = a.rows[0].cells
w = heading_cells[1].text.add_run('Col 1')
w.bold = True
i = heading_cells[2].text = 'Col 2'
i.bold = True
```

This is giving me the message:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add_run'
```

I'm struggling to find the correct syntax for this, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a several options, but this is one that might suit in your case:

```
table = document.add_table(rows=5, cols=7)
heading_cells = table.rows[0].cells
run = heading_cells[1].paragraphs[0].add_run('Col 1')
run.bold = True
```

Comment: perfect! I couldn't nail the syntax. Thanks alot.